# Change default sorting order for specific woocommerce category archive

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, date, woocommerce

In Woocommerce, I am trying to change the default sorting order of the **"New"** Products category archive page decreasing by date order, so that the newest additions are listed first.

I have tried 2 different code snippets. Both change the default order but are showing the oldest products first.

I have changed the ASC to DESC in both snippets and both provided no change to the sort order.

I am VERY new to coding and appreciate any help with where I'm going wrong.

First attempt:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', 'custom_default_catalog_orderby' );

function custom_default_catalog_orderby() {

    $product_category = array( 'new' );

    if ( is_product_category( $product_category ) ) {
        return 'date_desc';
    }
}
```

The second attempt:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_catalog_ordering_args', 20, 1 );
function custom_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
    $product_category = 'new'; // <== HERE define your product category

    // Only for defined product category archive page
    if( ! is_product_category($product_category) ) return $args;

    // Set default ordering to 'date ID', so "Newness"
    $args['orderby'] = 'date ID';

    if( $args['orderby'] == 'date ID' )
        $args['order'] = 'DESC'; // Set order by DESC

    return $args;
}
```

Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try instead the following complete code that works for orderby "Date" in "DESC" Order for a specific defined product category archive page only:

```
// Utility conditional function targetting specific product category archive page
function is_product_category_orderby(){
    // HERE your specific product category setting
    return is_product_category('new');
}

// Set custom orderby "Date DESC" for specific product category archive
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'enable_catalog_ordering_by_date_desc' );
function enable_catalog_ordering_by_date_desc( $args ) {
    if ( isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) && is_product_category_orderby() ) {
        if ( 'date_desc' == $_GET['orderby'] ) {
            return array(
                'orderby'  => 'date ID',
                'order'    => 'DESC',
            );
        }
        // Make a clone of "menu_order" (the default option)
        elseif ( 'natural_order' == $_GET['orderby'] ) {
            return array( 'orderby'  => 'menu_order title', 'order' => 'ASC' );
        }
    }
    return $args;
}

// Add custom orderby "Date DESC" option for specific product category archive
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'add_catalog_orderby_date_desc' );
function add_catalog_orderby_date_desc( $orderby_options ) {
    if ( is_product_category_orderby() ) {
        // Insert "Sort by modified date" and the clone of "menu_order" adding after others sorting options
        return array(
            'date_desc' => __("Sort by decreasing date ", "woocommerce"),
            'natural_order' => __("Sort by natural shop order", "woocommerce"), // <== To be renamed at your convenience
        ) + $orderby_options ;
    }
    return $orderby_options ;
}

// Set default orderby to "Date DESC" option for specific product category archive
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', 'default_catalog_orderby_date_desc' );
function default_catalog_orderby_date_desc( $default_orderby ) {
    if ( is_product_category_orderby() )
        $default_orderby = 'date_desc';

    return $default_orderby;
}

// Set default orderby query to "Date DESC" option for specific product category archive
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'product_query_by_date_desc' );
function product_query_by_date_desc( $q ) {
    if ( ! isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) && is_product_category_orderby() && ! is_admin() ) {
        $q->set( 'orderby', 'date ID' );
        $q->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

[image]

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you! Not sure why the return order would not change with the ASC or DESC argument.